# ios - SizeToFit on UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, uiimageview, sizetofit

I have a UIImageView which loads in images from the documents directory on the ios file system .

The problem is that when I call

```
[imageView sizeToFit];
```

It does not work. I think it is because the image hasn't loaded fully at that point and so the sizeToFit part is called before it has the image width & height.

Could someone point me in the direction of a fix please.

Here is my code:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[FileOperations getLibraryPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", listData.imageId]]];
[imageView sizeToFit];
[imageScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
imageScroll.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
imageScroll.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
imageScroll.minimumZoomScale = 1;
imageScroll.maximumZoomScale = 2;
[imageScroll setZoomScale:imageScroll.minimumZoomScale];
[imageScroll addSubview:imageView];
```

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "It does not work"? Does it have the wrong size?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using one of `UIImageView`'s `Mode` values like "Aspect Fit"?

Comment: By "It does not work", I mean that it is being viewed at 100%, and the images are much larger than the iPhone itself.

Comment: @mbm30075 Actually I am, but I messed up the copy/paste. Changing now.

Comment: As I read the documentation, `sizeToFit` isn't the preferred way to do this. Also, since the contentMode is set prior to loading the image, I would think it would size appropriately itself at load time. Have you checked the value of `[comicViewer frame].size`?

Comment: @AshleyStaggs Then your understanding of UIView's `sizeToFit` is wrong. `sizeToFit` resizes your UIImageView to match the size of the image, not the other way around. What you want is most likely what @mbm30075 suggested (`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`), so you might want to remove the `sizeToFit` and set your imageView's `frame` manually.

Comment: @AndreasLey I don't know how to set the frame manually when the image being loaded is not a set size.

Comment: @AndreasLey I just took out the [imageView sizeToFit] and the image loaded, but was not displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the image size:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(imageView.image.size));
```

You may want to set `imageView` frame based on the image size manually, for example, if the image is too large to fit the `imageView`'s superview.

Comment: That should be `NSStringFromCGSize(imageView.image.size)`

Comment: the answer was to just set the frame of imageView to be half of the actual image size. Thanks to Costique & @AndreasLey

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
myImage.image = [UIImage imageName:@"image.png"];
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeToFit` should work in your situation, but fails if the UIImage is nil.

UIImage's `imageWithContentsOfFile:` returns a (completely loaded) reference to a `UIImage` or `nil`. Are you sure that you're passing the right path?