# UIImageView overflowing its containing UIView after calling sizeToFit

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, sizetofit

My `UIView` (width: 352px) has a `UIImageView` subview (default width in Storyboard: 312px).
I want the `UIImageView` to adapt itself to the dimensions of the image it contains with the constraint that the width of the image view shouldn't exceed a maximal width size (in my case,  312px).
I set up the 'autosizing' configuration of my `UIImageView` to have a fixed left, top and right margin size. Nevertheless, when I call `sizeToFit` on my `UIImageView` and its image is larger than 352px, the `UIImageView` gets wider than its containing UIView.
Is there a convenient method to prevent such a behavior without doing the math based on the image dimensions? Am I using `sizeToFit` the right way?

Comment: Have you tried aspect fit? (`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`).

Comment: This should be of help to you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452047/ios-sizetofit-on-uiimageview-not-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452047/ios-sizetofit-on-uiimageview-not-working)

Comment: @ohr : yes i have - same behavior

Comment: @Rick : the link you mention says you should do the math manually and i already knew it was an option. What I want to know is why sizeToFit can't help: am i not using it properly or is it just not the right method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Just use setClipsToBounds:

```
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks but that would clip the image. That's not what i want. :)

Comment: If you use sizeToFit, the ImageView will grow up to fit the image, instead you can set this property: 


[imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight]; 

and comment this line
 [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit]; 
to work fine.